# Should I quote numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql

I remember reading about quoting stuff when doing a SQL query and that when you quote something, it becomes a string. I also read that numbers should not be quoted. Now, I can't find that quotation and I need to refresh my memory to see if I should quote numbers.

Comment: Depends on how the value is stored in the db.  If stored as text, quote it, if stored as a number don't :-)

Comment: That is not a number, that is a code. Like a produce ID or similar. A number is something you use for calculation. A number should not be quoted, since a number should never be stored in the database as a string.

Comment: @Someone do you have a source for your definition that an ID composed of numeric digits is not a number and therefore should be quoted?  And what if it's an ID that corresponds to rows in a table like 1 for row1 e.t.c?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should not quote numbers if you want to treat them as numbers.

You're correct by remembering that it makes it a string.

```
SELECT 10 AS x
```

is perfectly legal and will return (in most database engines) a column of datatype int (or a variation thereof.)

If you do this:

```
SELECT '10' AS x
```

instead you'll get a textual data type. This might too be suitable in some cases, but you need to decide whether you want the result as text or as a number.

Comment: Numeric primary keys would also fall under this definition. They only include digits, but they are codes. Does it make sense to put quotes around a primary key?

Comment: No, it does not, and I removed the last part of my answer as it is an opinion, not suitable for an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example, where quoting would produce inconsistent results (in MySQL):

```
select 1 < 1.0;      // returns 0

select '1' < '1.0';  // returns 1
```

That's because the second comparison is performed using the current string collation rather than numerically.

It's better not to quote numbers, since that would just be an extra unnecessary step for the database to convert the string literal into a numeric value for comparison and could alter the meaning of comparisons.

Comment: are single quotes ok for most db engines? Postgres in particular at this time.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is for Microsoft SQL Server, in particular MSSQL 2008 R2.

In handwritten SQL I would never quote numbers (unless inserting a value into a varchar column where the string inserted just happens to be a number).  But sometimes when generating SQL programmatically it can make life simpler to just quote everything.  (This is in database maintenance scripts or library routines that work on any table, without knowing the column types in advance.)

I wondered whether doing so would impose a performance penalty.  If I've used a quoted value in my SQL statement, the server must parse it as a string and then have to convert it to integer.  But then, parsing SQL would involve converting strings to integers anyway.  And the query parse time is usually only a small fraction of the total.

I ran some test statements looking like

```
insert into #t values (123, 123, 123), (123, 123, 123)
insert into #t values ('123', '123', '123'), ('123', '123', '123')
```

but with a larger number of columns in `#t`, a larger number of value tuples inserted in one go, and each statement repeated many times.  I happened to use Perl for that:

```
$dbh = my_database_connection(); # using DBD::Sybase
$n = 20; # this many value tuples, and also repeated this many times
$v = "'123'";
# $v = 123;    # uncomment this to insert without quoting

@cols = 'aa' .. 'zz';
@ds = map { "[$_] int not null" } @cols;
@vs = map { $v } @cols;
$" = ", ";
$dbh->do("create table #t (@ds)");
foreach (1 .. $n) {
    $sql = 'insert into #t values ';
    $sql .= "(@vs), " foreach 1 .. $n;
    $sql =~ s/, \z//;
    $dbh->do($sql);
}
```

but you can trivially write the same benchmark in any language.  I ran this several times for the quoted case and for the unquoted, and observed no significant difference in speed.  (On my setup a single run took about ten seconds; you can obviously change `$n` to make it faster or slower.)

Of course, the generated SQL is bigger if it has the redundant quote characters in it.  It surely can't be any faster, but it does not appear to be noticeably slower.

Given this result, I will simplify my SQL-generation code to add single quotes around all values, without needing to know the data type of the column to be inserted into.  (The code does still need to defend against SQL injection by making sure the input value doesn't itself contain the ' character, or otherwise quoting cleverly.)

I still don't recommend quoting numbers in SQL in the normal course of things, but if you find you have to do it, it doesn't appear to cause any harm.  Similarly, in generated code I put `[]` around column names whether needed or not, but I consider that unnecessary cruft in handwritten SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you may have read, but don't quote numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, don't forget to check to make sure any value you passed is really a number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at the risk of igniting a flame, may I respectfully disagree a little here that it is NEVER ok to use single quotes around a numeric value? It seems to me that it SOMETIMES makes sense to use single quotes around a numeric value. If col1 is an INT column, then (using vbscript as an example)

```
sql = "INSERT " & foo & " INTO col1 WHERE ID = 1"
```

and

```
sql = "INSERT '" & foo & "' INTO col1 WHERE ID = 1"
```

will BOTH, when sql is executed, insert any integer value of foo correctly. But what if you want 0 to be inserted when foo is not initialized? Using a quoted numeric expression like this prevents an error and handles the null case. Whether or not you think this is good practice, it is certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

eh... no you shouldn't?

I assume you mean by quoting *enclosing in* ' `like 'this'`

`INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES (999);` is perfectly legal as long as foo is an INT type collumn
`INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES('foo');` Inserts the string foo into the table. You can't do this on INT type tables of course.