# Incorrect syntax error near keyword read,when I update

Tags: php, sql-server

```
update cometchat set read='1' where id='18'
```

> SQL Error 156:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'read'.

Can you guys help me how do I do that?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Rizier123: Based on the error message, the database in question is not MySql, but Sql Server, so this is **not** a duplicate of the post you've chosen.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Your right, I just saw the mysql tag. Then it should be closed with: http://stackoverflow.com/q/285775

Comment: @Rizier123 Agree. voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Holiday Tourism  you have answers below. Check them and mark one as accepted answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Read` is a reserved word. You need to escape it.
Also, if the values are integers, you should not use the single quotes around them.

If It's Sql Server (and it is, based on the error message), you need to use square brackets:

```
update cometchat set [read]=1 where id=18
```

In MySql, your query should look like this:

```
update cometchat set `read`=1 where id=18
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put quotes around int values in your query as it converts them to type string.

[Should I quote numbers in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078942/should-i-quote-numbers-in-sql)

```
UPDATE cometchat SET `read`=1 WHERE id=18
```

**Edit:
You're also using a reserved keyword, and need to escape it, see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Seriously...

```
UPDATE cometchat SET `read`=1...
```

"read" is a restricted keyword. It needs to be quoted.